# "Boiling is to evaporation as melting is to... ?" Or, why aren't 31 degree ice cubes wet?

Tags: temperature, phase-transition

Well before a liquid reaches boiling point, it gradually looses molecules with exceptionally high kinetic energies to its surroundings, which is called evaporation.  Does this phenomenon occur to some solids as well, where before their melting points, the lose some of their mass into liquid forms?  Why don't ice cubes at 31 degrees have a layer of water sticking to them, but are instead extremely dry?

Comment: This is not a duplicate of https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/407929/  because this question is not about sublimation.

Comment: On a physics forum you need to be more specific about units.  Note that $31^\circ$F is just below $0^\circ$C so why wouldn't they be wet sounds pretty trivial to someone reading that as Fahrenheit.

Answer (score 3):

They do, although its very thin.

The three phases of matter are merely approximations which let us treat a whole bunch of molecules as if they were a bulk object.

However, when a liquid molecule gains enough energy to act gas-like, it tends to get away from the liquid body.  When a molecule of a solid gets enough energy to act like a liquid, it stays near the solid, giving it an opportunity to transfer some of that energy back into the solid, effectively "refreezing".

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the  [phase diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_(data_page)#Phase_diagram) of water you will see that below the temperature of the triple point, ice turns directly into vapour rather than into liquid. In other words it *sublimates*